# Algebra with a little trig problem?.

Tags: trigonometry

$\frac{1}{r\tan \left(\frac{\alpha}{2} \right)} = a$

$\frac{1}{\tan \left(\frac{\alpha}{2} \right)} = b$

$\frac{f}{(f-n)} = c$

-$\frac{nf}{(f-n)} = d$

Solve what you can first:

$\alpha = 2\arctan\left(\frac{1}{b} \right)$

using this: solve for r:

r = $\frac{1}{\left(a\tan \left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\right)} = \frac{1}{\left(a\tan\left(\frac{2\arctan\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)}{2}\right)\right)} = \frac{1}{\left(a\tan\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)\right)\right)} = \frac{b}{a}$

How does $\frac{1}{\left(a\tan\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)\right)\right)} = \frac{b}{a}$ ?

please show exact steps

Comment: $\tan(x)$ and $\arctan(x)$ are inverses of one another. So $\tan(\arctan(x))=x$ and $\arctan(\tan(x))=x$. Therefore, $\tan(\arctan(1/b))=1/b$

Answer (score 3):

$$\tan(\arctan (x)) = \arctan(\tan (x)) = x$$

Applying that to your problem:

$$\frac{1}{a\cdot \left(\tan\left(\arctan\left(\frac 1b\right)\right)\right)} = \frac 1{a\cdot \left(\frac 1b\right)} = \frac 1{\frac ab} = \frac ba$$

Note that in the last equality, be have $$\frac 1{\frac ab}= \frac 1{\frac ab}\cdot \frac bb = \frac ba$$